# For loop alternative for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-function

Lets assume I have a tax generating module on which the tax for certain range of amount is dynamic. The range is stored on a table like:

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|   range_from  |   range_to    |   rate    |
+---------------+---------------+-----------+   
|        0          1000            25      |
|       1001        5000            30      |
|       5001        8000            40      |
|       8000          -             50      |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

This range table can have any number of rows.

So, how can I achieve the tax amount from above table using function on MySQL ?

If I provide 20000, it should calculate like

```
  1000 * 0.25 + 4000 * 0.30 + 3000 * 0.40 + 12000 * 0.50
```

I tried to use,

```
  set @remaining_amount = @provided_amount;
  for x in (select * from range_table)
  loop
      if(@provided_amount > x.range_to) 
        set @tax_amt+=(x.range_to-x.range_from)* x.rate/100;
        set @remaining_amt-= x.range_to-x.range_from; 
      end if;
      if(@provided_amount > x.range_from and x.range_to = '-') 
        set @tax_amt+=(@remaining_amount)* x.rate/100;
      end if;
  end loop;
```

but I didn't find "for loop" working on MySQL.

Any suggestions/ help ?

Comment: Its 5.1.51 for now, but lets assume it as 5+ cause other system on which the system has to be get deployed may have lower version.

Comment: Check my answer. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
SUM(IF(x < range_from, 0, 
        IF(x < range_to OR range_to IS NULL, (x - range_from)*rate*0.01, 
                                             (range_to - range_from)*rate*0.01))
```

Comment: what is x here ? I didn't understand your query.